# Tap Gesture To Dismiss Keyboard Seems To Disables didSelectRow

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I have added the following code to my viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(hideKeyBoard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and this somewhere within my .m file as well

```
-(void)hideKeyBoard {
    [theEditableTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [theEditableTextView resignFirstResponder];


}
```

Which works fine for dismissing the keyboard when tapping outside of the textfield/view BUT i have added a table view and i need to be able to select a town and i cannot select a row with this code.

How can i disable the keyboard when tapping outside of a textfield or textview but still be able to use didSelectRow for the table view?

Comment: Instead of this approach it may be better to use an `inputAccessoryView` with the text field/view. Have the accessory view include a button that dismisses the keyboard.

Comment: this seem to work for me tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seem to do the trick

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```